# capture a web page with html and svg content using only javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, screenshot, html

My requirements are to take screen shot of a web page which has both html and svg content and send it by mail. Image format can be jpeg.

I have searched a lot and found phantom.js but I am not allowed to use it. So need your help.

Thanks alot

Comment: try this [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=screenshot+using+java+script&oq=screenshot+using+java+script&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i60l4.4516j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=screenshot+using+javascript&safe=off&spell=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HussainAkhtarWahid but almost all the links tend to capture only the html content using canvas and svg content is left blank :(